# Division by 0 when combining tikzpicture and resizebox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

To draw a larger tree, I tried to use

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\Tree [.CP  ] 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives a division by 0 error. However, without the `tikzpicture`
environment, it works just fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\Tree [.CP  ] 
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\resizebox` needs to be outside the `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` environment.